# What do Islam say about mercy killing?

Tags: practical-islam

i want to know what Islams says about mercy killing. Does Islam allow killing someone who is very ill, in order to stop them suffering any more pain or it is forbidden in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, life is a sacred thing that can only be taken by Allah or based on Allah's commands. The person in question (whose life it is) has no choice in the matter in either case either to keep his life or to take it. It is not his life or body to give or harm.

Suicide is specifically banned in many hadith:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "He who commits suicide by throttling shall keep on throttling himself in the Hell Fire (forever) and he who commits suicide by stabbing himself shall keep on stabbing himself in the Hell-Fire." ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1365))
>
> --
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Whoever swears by a religion other than Islam, is, as he says; and whoever commits suicide with something, will be punished with the same thing in the (Hell) Fire; and cursing a believer is like murdering him; and whoever accuses a believer of disbelief, then it is as if he had killed him." ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/31))

Referring specifically to mercy killing, it can be likened to the situation in the following hadith:

> We witnessed (the battle of) Khaibar. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said about one of those who were with him and who claimed to be a Muslim. "This (man) is from the dwellers of the Hell-Fire." When the battle started, that fellow fought so violently and bravely that he received plenty of wounds. Some of the people were about to doubt (the Prophet's statement), but **the man, feeling the pain of his wounds, put his hand into his quiver and took out of it, some arrows with which he slaughtered himself** (i.e. committed suicide). Then some men amongst the Muslims came hurriedly and said, "O Allah's Apostle! Allah has made your statement true so-and-so has committed suicide. "The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "O so-and-so! Get up and make an announcement that none but a believer will enter Paradise and that Allah may support the religion with an unchaste (evil) wicked man.([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/243))

The hadith makes it clear that it was seen as a great sin akin to disbelief itself to commit suicide to avoid pain. I don't believe it would make a difference if it is another person doing the actual killing.

In conclusion, mercy killing is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

No Islam does not allow killing someone who is very ill .It is forbidden in Islam because Allah create every single person and Everyone is died on their own time no one have to right to kill anyone.It is against in Islam. Eclveryone's life is in the hand of Allah.
Islam says ; killing one person is equal to killing the whole humanity. 
And if the person is very ill and suffering it means his or her guilt was less in his life and after his or her death Allah forgive them and he or she entered in heaven.